# Expanding ClientID in an event string

Tags: asp.net, javascript, clientid

I'm having a problem with <%= obj.ClientID %> expansion, in a .ascx user control.

I have a .js file, containing a javascript function:

```
function doSomething(objectId)
{
    ...
}
```

I have a .ascx file, with some html elements, and in one element's onclick= I want to call doSomething(), passing the ID of an element in that .ascx file, where the passed ID is of an element other than the one being clicked on, so I can't use "this.".

Maybe it'd be clearer with an example.

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect()
    {
        doSomething('<%= top.ClientID %>');
    }
</script>
<div id="top" runat="server">
    <img src="..." alt="..." onclick="redirect();"/>
</div>
```

But this does not:

```
<div id="top" runat="server">
    <img src="..." alt="..." onclick="doSomething('<%= top.ClientID %>');"/>
</div>
```

When I look at the source, I see that the <%= %> substitution has not happened, instead of "doSomething('ctl00_myControl_top');" I get "doSomething('<%= top.ClientID %>');"

For some reason, the script expansion happens in the former case, but not in the latter.  The work-around, of course, is not acceptable because it will break if I include multiple copies of the control on a page - only one instance's "redirect()" function will be accessible.

Any ideas on how to make this substitution work?

Comment: You have the div inside a form tag that's runat='server' right?

Comment: The entire server control is included inside a form tag with runat="server", div and script sections both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works on my machine?

```
<div id="top" runat="server">
    <a href="#" onclick="doSomething('<%= top.ClientID %>')">rarrarara</a>
</div>
```

Becomes

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_top">
    <a href="#" onclick="doSomething('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_top')">rarrarara</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd expected it to, on my machine, which is why I was so surprised when it didn't.  I thought I'd checked out all the ridiculously obvious mistakes, maybe I haven't.

Comment: Trying adding an ID and a runat="server" to your anchor.  It seems that if I have a runat="server" tag on the element that has the onclick event, the <% %> expansion doesn't happen.

Comment: This is, apparently, something that Microsoft has decided not to support.  Google on this error message: "Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.".

The solution is to do an Attributes.Add("onclick", "") in the code-behind.

Comment: Ah, well your example didn't have a runat="server" on the img tag :)

Answer (score 0):

**Consider an alternate route:**

Ensure that the control you are referencing in JavaScript using the inline expression `<%= (controlName).ClientID %>` has its 'ClientIDMode' specifier set to a static value and then simply use the text in the ID field of that control to refer to it.  I ended up using this in a recent project it works great.  Please see the link below for a more detailed explanation:

[Code Project - ASP.NET v4.0 Client ID Feature](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature)

Along with setting the 'ClientIDMode' specifier to "Static", I found a useful idea regarding placing text from a global resource file (in the case of language switching) into a field of a standard HTML control that does not have to run at the server level.  I used this on a standard HTML button that was supposed to call a JavaScript function that would show/hide a specific div or ASP Panel. Use the GlobalResource function in the inline expression tags like so:

```
<input id="btnToggleFilterOptions" type="button" value="<%=GetGlobalResourceObject("SiteResource", "btnToggleFilterOption")%>" onclick="javascript:ToggleCssClass('divFilterOption','visible'); return false;" class="button submit" />

<asp:Panel ID="divFilterOption" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilterOption1" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I know this is an old post, but it is a popular hit when searching on Google for Asp .NET and ClientID.  I hope this helps somebody else out!